# Help with dirac delta derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Prove that

$\sigma_{n}=n^{3}$sin$[nx+\frac{1}{n}]\delta(nx)-n\delta(x-\frac{1}{n})$

has the distributional limit 
$\lim_{n\to\infty } \sigma_{n}=\delta'(x).$

I know that $\delta'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\delta(x+h)-\delta(x)}{h}$ but i fail to see how I can use this. Any hints, guidence or help is welcomed.

Comment: Do you know alternative expressions for $\delta(c x)$ and for $f(x) \delta(x)$?

Comment: I know that $\delta(cx)=\frac{1}{|c|}\delta(x)$ and $\delta(f(x))$ but not $f(x)\delta(x)$.

Comment: I'm not sure how you have introduced the distributions. But it should be easy enough to show that $f(x) \delta(x) =f(0) \delta(x)$ for continuous $f(x)$. Can you apply these two results to the first term?

Comment: Well, i can apply the result of $\delta(cx)$ to get $n^{2}$sin$[nx+\frac{1}{n}]\delta(x)$ and take $f(x)$ as$n^{2}$sin$[nx+\frac{1}{n}]$

Answer (score 0):

Given the two "facts"
$$ \delta(c x) = \frac{1}{|c|} \delta(x), \text{ and } f(x) \delta(x) = f(0) \delta(x)$$
for $c$ constant and $f$ continuous, we obtain
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sigma_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} n^2 \sin(n^{-1}) \delta(x) - n \delta(x-1/n).$$
Now set $h=n^{-1}$ and observe that $h\to0$ when $n\to\infty$, so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sigma_n = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\overbrace{h^{-1}\sin h}^{1+O(h^2)}\, \delta(x) - \delta(x-h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\delta(x) - \delta(x-h)}{h} + O(h)  = \delta'(x)  $$

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the two following properties of $\delta$

$$\begin{align}\delta(cx)&={1\over |c|}\delta(x)\\f(x)\delta(x)&=f(0)\delta(x)\end{align}$$

we can write

$$E(x,n)=n^3\sin\left(nx+{1\over n}\right)\delta(nx)-n\delta\left(x-{1\over n}\right)=n\sin{1\over n}\times n\delta(x)-n\delta\left(x-{1\over n}\right)$$

Now consider that as $n\to\infty$ we have $n\sin{1/n}\to 1$ and so

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}E(x,n)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\delta(x)-\delta\left(x-{1\over n}\right)\right)\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}{\delta(x)-\delta\left(x-h\right)\over h}\end{align}$$